# Validate group of Textboxes on the same page

Tags: php, jquery

i am working on a project ... i am using php and jquery . i want a way to validate dynamically generated text boxes with  the same class name,  when i click the submit button ..and should be able to  detect empty fields by highlighting them in red ..using jquery

I really need a hand in this

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Take a look at [this plugin](http://elclanrs.github.com/jq-idealforms/), problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

For jQuery, current flavour of the year/month for fom validation is http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation.

No point really repeating the examples here, as it's well documented: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Example

Basically, you assign a class to the fields and add a validator that responds to the class. Some classes are standard (e.g. "required" means the field is compulsory) but you can add your own, add call backs etc. And it adds a "error" class to the input so you can style that class to make it red.